# How to use isolate scope inside directive's controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have something very simple, similar like below. My question is how to make the isolate scope available inside the directive's controller: ([For a full jsbin version, click here!](http://jsbin.com/rivezo/1/edit?html,js,console,output))

```
app.directive("data", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div>My Data</div>",
    scope: {
      myData : '='
    },
    require: "data",
    controller: function(){
      this.logData = function(){
        console.log(scope.myData);
      }
    },
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl){
      console.log(scope.myData); //works!
      ctrl.logData(); //scope is not defined
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the scope reference, just like with the regular controllers. Here's a quick example:

```
controller: function($scope){
  this.logData = function(){
    console.log($scope.myData);
  }
},
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/oossm0g48PnPc3e89P2v?p=preview

Comment: so is it true that the directive controller's "$scope" has access to the isolated scope of the directive?

Comment: Yes, they are accessing the same scope (you'll see scope id 2 for both if you log them in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bindToController property to bind declared
properties in isolate scope directly to controller instance used inside the directive. Follow an example of DDO object inside directive function declaration:

```
var ddo = {
templateUrl: 'example.html',
scope: {
  articles: '<',
  title: '@'
},
controller: ExampleDirectiveController,
controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
bindToController: true
```

};

The bindToController setted true allow you to use isolate scope properties (in this case articles and title) directly inside your controller.